# BottomNavigationView: Disable animation for adding/inflating menu runtime

Tags: android, animation, bottomnavigationview

I have a problem with BottomNavigationView. I have to inflate menu runtime and I have a problem with default animation. It looks like tabs slide from right.
Do you know how to disable this animation/behavior?

[image: Default animation]

XML:

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@null"
            app:itemBackground="@null"
            app:itemIconSize="75dp"
            app:itemRippleColor="@null"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled" />
```

Replacing menu runtime:

```
 binding.navigation.menu.clear()
 binding.navigation.inflateMenu(menuId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved problem by using TransitionManager.endTransitions(...)

```
binding.navigation.menu.clear()
binding.navigation.inflateMenu(menuId)
TransitionManager.endTransitions(binding.navigation.getChildAt(0) as NavigationBarMenuView)
```

Maybe it will help someone else. If you have better way to solve this let me know. Thanks in advance!